# How to prevent database trigger updating @@identity after Insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am adding a trigger to an existing database table, which is used by an application I did not code, and cannot change the code in.

I want to insert some information from `TableA` into `TableB` on `INSERT` into `TableA`.

1. Application runs `INSERT INTO TableA` <-- this updates `@@identity`
2. An `ON INSERT` trigger that runs on `TableA` then inserts data into `TableB` <-- this also updates the `@@identity` with a new value
3. Application reads `@@identity` <-- which is from `TableB` not from `TableA` as the application is expecting

Is there any way to **not update** the `@@identity` from within the trigger?

Comment: There is no way to prevent that happening. That is one big reason you should never use @@identity.

Comment: Yeah, I know :) third-party application!

Comment: A very, very (no, seriously **very**) ugly workaroud: Issue an `INSERT` at the end of the trigger (into some temp table) that causes `@@identity` to be set to the desired value. Or, maybe a bit cleaner but more work, think about an `INSTEAD OF` trigger reversing the order of the `INSERT`s, so that the actual one is done last.

Comment: "3rd party application" generally implies that you are not legally allowed to modify the schema. Adding a trigger is such a modification - be careful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

....since @@identity has no scope you could create your own scope which carries the @@identity value at the end of the trigger

```
create table tableA(idA int identity(100, 1), colA int)
go

create table tableB(idB int identity(1000, 1), colB int)
go

create trigger triggerA on tableA
for insert
as
begin

    if not exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        return;
    end

    declare @tableA@@identity int = @@identity;

    select @@identity as [@@identity_triggerA_in];

    --add rows to tableB
    insert into tableB(colB)
    select object_id
    from sys.all_objects

    select @@identity as [@@identity_after_insert_in_tableB];


    if @tableA@@identity is not null
    begin
        declare @sql varchar(100) = concat('create table #t(id int identity(', @tableA@@identity, ',1)); insert into #t default values');
        exec (@sql);
    end

    select @@identity as [@@identity_triggerA_out];

end
go  

insert into tableA(colA) values (10);
select @@identity;

go

insert into tableA(colA)
select top (200) 1
from sys.all_objects;
select @@identity;
go


insert into tableA(colA)
select 1
where 1=2;

select @@identity;

go

drop table tableA;
go
drop table tableB;
go
```

Comment: Thanks @lptr, not ideal, but does indeed work!